# Messenger bot, safety of parsing user ID to a webview URL as a parameter

Tags: webview, facebook-messenger, url-parameters, facebook-messenger-bot, userid

I'm currently building a food ordering Messenger bot that uses an extension for the menu, as it is a much faster way to browse and select in the restaurant menu rather than using carousel or lists and repeated questions about the quantity.

However, using extensions currently limits the use to mobile users. An extension is used(rather than a plain web-view) to get the user messenger id to determine which user is making the order. An idea came across my mind to switch to a regular web-view to allow desktop users to use the bot, as currently the messenger opens the web-views in a frame rather than in a new tab, but this means that the only way to determine which user is ordering is to pass the user ID (bot`s database user table ID, not the messenger ID) as a URL parameter for the menu.

My question is, how safe and is it even a good idea to do so?

Answer (score 0):

This would depend on how sensitive the user ID is. If the API that accesses your database is properly secured, then it should not be a problem, since no personally identifiable information can be extracted with just the user ID.

If you wanted to be really safe and not expose the user ID from the database at all, you could store the PSID from Messenger in the user db record, then send and do a look up on that instead.

So, I guess the short answer is, it's as secure or insecure as anything you would pass around over HTTP, since the webview in Messenger is a plain webview.

Comment: As of now, obtaining the user id that way, means anybody can make an order acting as that user, however the answer/conversation will continue forward with the true user (since it will match it's messenger id). All other actions require authentication (from the restaurant staff).

Comment: Sounds to me like you have a bigger security issue if just the user ID allows someone to place an order.

Answer (score 0):

First, although this may have been different when you posted your question, Messenger Extensions now absolutely do work on the desktop versions of Messenger (both when using messenger.com directly from the desktop, as well as when using the version of Messenger embedded within facebook.com). That said, I would recommend using the Content-Security-Policy directive to allow both messenger.com and facebook.com to display your webview as a frame within the browser, rather than the X-Frame-Options recommended by Facebook at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webview/extensions#webview_on_web . X-Frame-Options forces you to choose a single domain (messenger.com or facebook.com) to allow your webview to appear on, whereas with Content-Security-Policy you can allow both.

Second, it's worth pointing out that even if using Messenger Extensions, if you're not validating the incoming data using signed_request, then anyone can spoof an order acting as that user. The instructions at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webview/context#signed describe how to validate incoming info from getContext() to ensure that the information really did come from Messenger.

Comment: I did notice that extensions now open on desktop, however, last time I tried, you could not get user ID with extension SDK on desktop.

Comment: You can get the page-scoped user ID from MessengerExtensions.getContext(), via the thread_context that's passed to the success callback: see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/messenger-extensions-sdk/getContext